# Does a turret going to "hostile" state, but not opening fire, disqualify the user from Foxiest of the Hounds?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm about half way through my second playthrough of the game now, and realised that on the first mission at Milwaukee Junction a turret did see me. My minimap went to "hostile", but the turret did not fire, and (as far as I can tell) no alarm sounded. Being seen by *any* turret appears to immediately turn the minimap to saying "hostile" -- there is no 'alarmed' phase for turrets, it appears.

Does this disqualify me from Foxiest of the Hounds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29048/what-is-the-criteria-of-foxiest-of-all-hounds

Comment: His question isn't answered in that question, but it should be. Therefore voting to close and suggesting the answers on the duplicate be improved.

Comment: @Wipqozn Actually his question was answered in the other question (although you need a brain to figure it out), a turret does not set off an alarm unless it opens fire (which is obvious because otherwise you would have heard an alarm) and it's stated in the other question that an alarm must go off to disqualify you from the achievement.

Comment: @MrSmooth Except the OP wasn't sure if an alarm went off. *(as far as I can tell) no alarm sounded.* This was part of the problem he was having, he wasn't sure if an alarm went off and he just missed it. Another thing to consider is the accepted answer, and the one with the most up votes states ***possibly hostile turrets or bots seeing you.*** This would just add more uncertainty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Areas with alarms have those red lights dotted all over the map. When those start to flash, it means the alarm has been triggered. This is how I usually tell, as sometimes I might accidentally set off the alarm without even knowing.

Just to answer your question, under normal circumstances, as mordi2k has mentioned, as long as a turret doesn't start shooting at you, then you are safe. However, in this case there is actually no Smooth Operator bonus for the first mission in the Sarif Manufacturing Plant, hence no danger of breaking the Foxiest of all Hounds achievement to start with.

You might want to read the answer I posted on this thread:

[Which missions can I earn the Ghost and/or Smooth Operator bonus on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30279/which-missions-can-i-earn-the-ghost-and-or-smooth-operator-bonus-on/30328#30328)

Answer (score 7):

**No**, as long as an alarm didn't go off, you should be safe.

Quotes from the Deus Ex wiki:

> This does NOT mean that you can never get an "Alerted" status from enemies, or even "Hostile" with open combat. It simply means that no alarms can be tripped, such as from a camera spotting you or a body, an alerted enemy touching an un-hacked alarm panel, etc.
>
> It is wise to upgrade your capture software to enable you to shutdown turrets and bots; while getting their attention does not cause an alarm directly, the gunfire will get anyone's attention in the room.

[Source](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Foxiest_of_the_Hounds)

Answer (score 0):

To the above it is clearly stated in many places that not only is it the case the smooth operator achievement doesnt give you the foxiest achievement but they actually say it is ill advised to even rely on these XP achievements as verification of having stayed on track for ultimately getting the foxiest of all fox achievement.

I will link sites but a for instance was offered,  suppose you took down a soldier, when you left the area you at that point heard no alarms but they found the body latter and set the alarm off, out of your detection, if you finish the level after they set off an alarm in that portion of the facility you will void the foxiest achievement. The deus wika also says to be extremely careful and given how much game play time is needed its best to reload if you are even a lottle unsure. I personally have a mini book i am writing down a save for each level..then underneath if i am concerned of a possible alarm i missed, and using a few saves 1to 3 IN each level if i am concerned and want to back track, if its a long level i may use 2 instead of one saves in a campaign in case i dont get the achievement but think i have an idea of where i might have blundered

But most important its unsafe or unwise to use a different XP achievement to substitute as an assurance you recieved a different game achievement.  Here are the links below:

http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Foxiest_of_the_Hounds

"It should be noted that simply getting all the bonuses does not guarantee the acquisition of the achievement. If, for example, the player leaves a body of a knocked out enemy in a place where other patrolling guards may potentially find him and completes the objective fast enough he will still get the Smooth Operator bonus. But eventually the body will be found and guards will sound an alarm (it may even happen out of player's sight), which in turn will nullify the Foxiest of the Hounds. So it is recommended to play cautiously and not to trust the XP rewards too much."

also check out the link for smooth operator in the above page as a newbie i have a limit on links i can post

Interesting things like a soldier seeing a knocked out buddy may trigger an alarmed state but they may or may not sound an alarm...however if a camera sees a downed body it will sound an alarm

This site is also expremely helpful as its intent is to serve as a walkthrough guide for ALL achievements in one playthrough so they also show secret achievements as well as focus on the foxiest approach and pacificst approach.

http://www.trueachievements.com/deus-ex-human-revolution-walkthrough.htm?page=2

Each subseqent page is dedicated to each sote in the game and a loose walkthrough highliting only the main points for the achievements vs detailed approaches and maps.

To the mods that delete my last post it was a continuation of THIS ..ie not just a post with a link...BEACAUSE your rules didnt allow me to include the third link as a contrasting option for those who would prefer the more detailed approach vs the water downed basics given in this post

******I can only do what site allows it didnt make that detailed guide any less helpful to walking people through it. I would rather you add it to this post please instead of deleting since my hands are tied at a noob status i cant even comment on my part 1 post because i am a noob. Its so restrictive we cant function let a lone maintain mod approved standards of content or substantial post content beyond links thank you